# Blueimp jquery upload get data attribute of upload button

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using jquery tabs on my page and I have multiple upload forms on it. I am initializing Fileupload like this:

```
    $('.fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '<?php echo SITE_URL; ?>/uploads/index.php?property_id=<?php echo $property_id; ?>&category_id='+SubCategoryID,
    });
```

In my pages I have file upload form like this:

```
    <form id="files-form-<?php echo $s_value['sub_id']; ?>" class="fileupload" action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    // $s_value['sub_id'] is the actual id of category/subcategory and it's pulled out from an array
    ...STANDARD STUFF...
            <div class="fileupload-buttons">
            <span class="fileinput-button">
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="start" data-subcateogryid="<?php echo $s_value['sub_id']; ?>">Start all uploads</button>
            <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
            ...STANDARD STUFF...
        </div>
     </form>
```

So my question is: How to add data-subcategoryid as a "GET" variable to Fileupload url (in my JS part it's "SubCategoryID" at the end which needs to be replaced with data attribute) ?